# Shiny R - arrangement of app

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am struggling on the arrangement of my app using Shiny for R Studio.

With my ui file being

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("stockVis"),

  verticalLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      helpText("Choose a stock ticker to examine, For example:
        ^HSI - Hang Seng, 
        ^N225 - Nikkei 225, 
        ^FTSE - FTSE 100, 
        Information will be collected from yahoo finance."),

      textInput("symb", "Symbol", "^FTSE"),

      dateRangeInput("dates", 
        "Date range",
        start = "2015-01-01", 
        end = as.character(Sys.Date())),

      submitButton("Analysis")), 



    fluidRow(
      column(6,plotOutput("plot")),column(6,plotOutput("ret.graph")),
      column(4,plotOutput("qq.plot")),column(4,plotOutput("histogram")),column(4,plotOutput("qq.line"))
    )    



  )
))
```

The app looks like the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd1cG.png

However in the blank top right space, I want a table to be there so I adjusting the ui file as follows

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("stockVis"),

  verticalLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      helpText("Choose a stock ticker to examine, For example:
        ^HSI - Hang Seng, 
        ^N225 - Nikkei 225, 
        ^FTSE - FTSE 100, 
        Information will be collected from yahoo finance."),

      textInput("symb", "Symbol", "^FTSE"),

      dateRangeInput("dates", 
        "Date range",
        start = "2015-01-01", 
        end = as.character(Sys.Date())),

      submitButton("Analysis")), 



    fluidRow(column(12,tableOutput("table"))
      column(6,plotOutput("plot")),column(6,plotOutput("ret.graph")),
      column(4,plotOutput("qq.plot")),column(4,plotOutput("histogram")),column(4,plotOutput("qq.line"))
    )    



  )
))
```

The only change from the previous ui is the addition of **column(12,tableOutput("table"))** in the fluidRow line. However this results in the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFDJo.png

Which has added the table but not in the correct space. I have tried using the mainPanel feature as well but I just can't seem to get the table in the top right space. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You may need to subset `fluidRow`s as per the [column nesting section in this article](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html).

Comment: or wrap a `fluidRow` around each row of columns.